# How to use a CSS grid with percentages and an unknown amount of columns?

Tags: css, css-grid

This is the layout I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

I'm currently doing it by:

### HTML

```
<div class="ft-Footer_Columns">
  <div class="ft-Footer_Column ft-Footer_Column-about">
    <h4 class="ft-Footer_Title">Title 1</h4>

    <p class="ft-Footer_Text">Text 1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="ft-Footer_Column ft-Footer_Column-links">
    <h4 class="ft-Footer_Title">Title 2</h4>

    <p class="ft-Footer_Text">Text 2</p>
  </div>

  <div class="ft-Footer_Column ft-Footer_Column-contact">
    <h4 class="ft-Footer_Title">Title 3</h4>

    <p class="ft-Footer_Text">Text 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.ft-Footer_Columns {    
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: calc(20px * 2);
  grid-template-columns: calc(5 / 12)fr calc(4 / 12)fr calc(3 / 12)fr;
}
```

This seems like quite a hacky way to achieve what I want.

Ideally I want to be able to do:

```
.ft-Footer_Columns {    
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: calc(20px * 2);
  grid-template-columns: calc(5 / 12 * 100%) calc(4 / 12 * 100%) calc(3 / 12 * 100%);
}
```

But this currently does `100% + ((20px * 2) * 2)`.

How would I achieve this percentage / fractal based layout without the hacky `calc()FR` way?

Comment: So you want a grid with an unknown number of columns, right? And how do you want their width to work? Equal width in all cases?

Comment: Also, why the `calc(20px * 2)` on the `grid-column-gap`? That's always equivalent to 40px. Why the need for `calc()`?

Comment: You can use just `grid-template-columns: 5fr 4fr 3fr;` as well. Since 5+4+3=12, it will automatically assign 5/12, 4/12 and 3/12 of the whole available width to the columns, respectively.

Comment: @Michael_B The `calc()` is because it was `calc(var(--Grid_Gutter * 2))` i just gave the compiled result.

Comment: The issue i have, is i know the amount of columns in this case (3), but with a gutter of `40px` how do i make sure the %'s don't go over 100%?

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn i wasn't aware you could go over 1fr. That could well be the answer

Comment: It is @IlyaStreltsyn! If you put that as an answer i'll happily accept it :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since you don't know the number of columns, you don't use the [**`grid-template-columns`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#track-sizing) property. This property defines an *explicit* grid, meaning the tracks are explicitly defined.

You may be looking for [**`grid-auto-columns`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#auto-tracks). This property defines the width of columns that are automatically created (this would be the *implicit* grid).

Try this:

```
grid-auto-columns: 1fr
```

With the `fr` unit, only the free space is distributed. This would be the space left after the gutters are factored in.

> [**7.2.3. Flexible Lengths: the `fr` unit**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#valdef-flex-fr)
>
> A flexible length or `<flex>` is a dimension with the `fr` unit, which represents a fraction of the **free space** in the grid container.
>
> [**free space**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#free-space)
>
> Equal to the available grid space minus the sum of the base sizes of
>   all the grid tracks (including gutters), floored at zero. If available
>   grid space is indefinite, the free space is indefinite as well.

Also – when you do have a defined number of columns – since we're dealing with proportions, you could match the `fr` values to your desired percentages. Something like this:

```
grid-template-columns: 42fr 33fr 25fr (instead of 42% 33% 25%).
```

One advantage of using `fr` here is that the gutter size is automatically deducted (to establish the free space, which is the only space `fr` uses). With percentages, you need to use `calc()`.

Comment: Maybe i misphrased the question, my bad. I know the number of columns, i want the columns to be `41.6666% 33.3333% 25%`. This is fine. When i add `grid-column-gap: 40px`. This now becomes `100% + 80px`. Which is too big. The answer was provided in the comments though. I was under the understanding that you couldn't go above `1fr`. `5fr 4fr 3fr` is that answer i was after. Thanks for your time though.

Comment: Then try `42fr 33fr 25fr`. We're dealing with proportions, so you could match the `fr` to the desired percentage. Except, with `fr`, the gutter size is automatically deducted. With percentages, you need to use `calc()`.

Comment: Just realised this comment is correct @Michael_B. Happy to accept this if you'd want to update your answer for it

Comment: If you want to force the cells to fit on one line `grid-auto-columns: 1fr; grid-auto-flow: column; grid-gap: 1em;`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow

Answer (score 3):

If you can define a minimum width value to the columns, the following code would be a good solution for establishing equal-width columns without overflow. I defined the value 100px here, but of course, you can change the value as you wish. The browser will try to put all the columns in a row by shrinking the width down to min-width. If there is overflow, it will put the remain columns second row. But the width of the columns would be the same anyway.

`

```
.ft-Footer_Columns {
    display: grid;
    grid-column-gap:20px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}
```

`